# Java: How to log where my function was called from

Tags: java

Is there a better way than wantonly throwing an exception and capturing the stacktrace to find out why (or at least from where) my function was called?

I can log the parameters the caller is using, but I cannot get the caller location itself. It is some third party software, so finding all references and adding log information there is not an option. I also hesitate attaching a debugger to a running jvm.

Comment: No need to throw the exception. Creating it is sufficient. All IDEs I know allow generating a call hierarchy, by statically analyzing the code. Maybe it's sufficient.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can call `Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()`.

This will give you an StackTrace array the same way you would get if you'd thrown an Exception.

Hope this helps.  :)

Comment: stack[0] is the method getStackTrace() itself, stack[1] is where I call your suggestion, stack[2] etc. is what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

It's perfectly possible to create an exception, not throw it, and inspect its stacktrace:

```
Exception e = new Exception();
e.printStackTrace(System.out);
```

Note that doing it often may have a detrimental effect on the performance of your JVM.

```
StackTraceElement[] stacktrace = e.getStackTrace();
```

The 0th element of the `stacktrace` array will contain the method in which the exception was instantiated.

Comment: `detrimental effect on the performance of your JVM`. Good point. I assumed it goes without saying that you would use this for debugging purpouses only, since needing to know where your function was called from is both bad design and very slow (inspecting stack trace is several times slower than calling a method, for example). However you can, of course, use this in fringe situations.

Comment: @kajacx: Agree with everything you said. I have a vague recollection of someone claiming that generating a stacktrace will freeze all threads on the JVM, but I do not have a source to back up this claim, so I'll omit it from the answer. Definitely a "debugging-only"-technique.

Comment: I had to look up "fringe situations" but your assumption was right, of course. I simply need to understand what's going on in this initial debugging phase. Thanks. Boschi's suggestion - without an exception - is limited to similar circumstances, I assume.

Comment: @datafiddler: I do not know of any inherent limitations in the approach he suggests. My recommendation would actually be for you to use that one. :) It's more readable and doesn't introduce an unneeded exception.

Comment: Going on a tangent here: one such "fringe situation" would be logging: If you want to log a warning message, it would be useful to know where was the message logged from, and best way to get that is from the stack trace. And since you would log into a file or at least into console, the stack inspection isn't that bad in comparison.

Comment: @kajacx: I would argue that this should be handled by naming your logger appropriately, typically by the name of the class in which it is embedded.

Comment: @Henrik but that would only give you the classname, not method name, line number, or the option to turn on deeper stack tracing. Plus you would have to write `private static Logger logger = new Logger(MyClass.class);` inside every single class, which would be a hassle. But if someone prefers that, I won't stop them.

Comment: @kajacx: That is actually the preferred approach in Java development at the moment. Several IDEs even include shortcuts to create the `logger` field in a class. :)