# Is there any way to pass the StackTraceElement on some Logging framework for Java?

Tags: java, logging

I am implementing an application with the Jsch library from JCraft, which is a Java implementation for ssh.

This library has a Logger interface which describes a log function as following

```
public void log(int level, String message);
```

Is there any way to implement it with something like this?

```
public void log(int level, String message)
{
    StackTraceElement trace = getTrace();
    LOGGER.log( trace, level, message);
}
```

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42534564/java-how-to-log-where-my-function-was-called-from

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `getTrace()` is suppose to return the call site of the logger statement you can create a new `Throwable` and [convert a stack trace to a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1149703/how-can-i-convert-a-stack-trace-to-a-string) or choose a [single frame and convert that to a string](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StackTraceElement.html#toString--).  Once you have the string representation of the trace you can concatenate that to the message string and send that to the target logging framework.

If your logging framework supports [Mapped Diagnostic Context](https://logback.qos.ch/manual/mdc.html) you can pass the throwable object or stacktrace element itself to the logging framework.  If you are using JUL you simply have to use [`Logger::logp`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/logging/Logger.html#logp-java.util.logging.Level-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) method to pass the call site information.

Answer (score 0):

From the current thread you can query the entire stacktrace, and leaving the current position `[0]` out, you have the call site of the `log` occurrence.

```
public void log(int level, String message) {
    StackTraceElement trace = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[1]; // Or 2?
    LOGGER.log(trace, level, message);
}
```

As nowadays exceptions often are chained (thrown furthers as cause), I am not sure whether a single stack trace element suffices.

Comment: I know the mechanism of StackTraceElement. I dont know how to pass the information on some logging framework, for example on SLF4J as Raedwald proposed.

Answer (score -2):

Instead of passing the stacktrace, you can pass the exception and have the logging framework print the stacktrace. This is possible through the [SLF4J](https://www.slf4j.org/apidocs/index.html) `Logger` interface and logging frameworks such as logback that conform to it.

Comment: There is no exception handling. Just ordinary logging messages